# Selecting recent 3 records for a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, subquery, limit

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT s.name,
       f.message,
       e.timestamp,
       e.result,
       o.details
FROM  event e
LEFT JOIN feed f ON e.id=f.id 
LEFT JOIN oper o ON o.id=e.id 
LEFT JOIN system s ON o.id=e.id 
WHERE (e.date = ’15-06-2020’)
AND e.oper_id IN (SELECT id from oper 
                               where state = ‘READY1’ or  state = ‘READY2’ or state = ‘READY2’
                               group by state
                               order by state)
```

Now I have more then 3 results in my e.results table, however I wanted to take only recent 3 results (so sort on timestamp). So my final result from SQL should be only have recent 3 results.

I tried doing (select e.result from event ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 3) in place of e.result, which is not working.

Any idea how could I achieve this. I am querying MySQL.

Comment: The subquery is not valid SQL (you are selecting `id` but grouping by `state`). Sample data and desired results would help clarifying your question.

Comment: Please do not use Word for formatting, and store dates using a DATE  datatype

Comment: Once you've addressed the issues identified above, please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

firstly make the order in descending order and set limit for 3 in sql right after the order by clause.
change the column in subquery.

```
SELECT s.name,
   f.message,
   e.timestamp,
   e.result,
   o.details FROM event e
   LEFT JOIN feed f ON e.id=f.id 
LEFT JOIN oper o ON o.id=e.id 
LEFT JOIN system s ON o.id=e.id 
WHERE (e.date = ’15-06-2020’) AND
e.oper_id IN (SELECT id,state from oper 
   where state = ‘READY1’ or  state = ‘READY2’
   group by state order by state desc LIMIT 3)
```

try this.